# How do I get the image url from an image field type

Tags: drupal, imagefield

I'm working on a module that will display images, so for this module I created a specific content type. One of the fields from this content type is an image, named field_ssimage.

I found the table in my database named field_data_field_ssimage, but there is no column that contains the URL. I was thinking of writing an SQL statement to get all my image URLs so that I could output them in the img tags, but to no prevail.

Where can I find this URL? Or am I approaching the problem in entirely the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields in Drupal get their own table as the table you mentioned. In your case table `field_data_{field_ssimage}` belongs to the `field_ssimage` field. In this table there is a column `{field_ssimage}_fid` containing the **File ID** of your image. In the `file_managed` table there is a record with corresponding `fid` having a **URI** value. So basically that's the table you'll be needing.

Make sure to render images to the frontend with the Drupal image theme function: 
[theme_image($variables)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)

Comment: Oh great, thanks a bunch! Didn't know which other table to look in.
Is it actually the 'correct' way to do this? I come from a database administrator background, so I'm more comfortable with SQL statements, which is why I thought of doing it this way.

Comment: Yes but make sure to get the data with the Drupal API. Take a look at [Static queries](https://www.drupal.org/node/310072). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks again. I've built my first module through a Drupal guide, and even for the select statement there they used a dynamic query. But is there a difference (performance, security, ...) between static and dynamic queries when talking about select statements?